# Where do standard library or compilers leverage noexcept move semantics (other than vector growth)?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, move-semantics

Move operations should be `noexcept`; in the first place for intuitive and reasonable semantics. The second argument is runtime performance. From the Core Guidelines, [C.66](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-move-noexcept), "Make move operations noexcept":

> A throwing move violates most people’s reasonably assumptions. A non-throwing move will be used more efficiently by standard-library and language facilities.

The canonical example for the performance-part of this guideline is the case when `std::vector::push_back` or friends need to grow the buffer. The standard requires a strong exception guarantee here, and this can only move-construct the elements into the new buffer if this is `noexcept` - otherwise, it must be copied. I get that, and the difference is visible in benchmarks.

However, apart from this, I have a hard time finding real-world evidence of the positive performance impact of `noexcept` move semantics. Skimming through the standard library (`libcxx` + `grep`), we see that `std::move_if_noexcept` exists, but it's almost not used within the library itself. Similarly, `std::is_noexcept_swappable` is merely used for fleshing out conditional `noexcept` qualifiers. This doesn't match existing claims, for example this one from "C++ High Performance" by Andrist and Sehr (2nd ed., p. 153):

> All algorithms use `std::swap()` and `std::move()` when moving elements around, but only if the move constructor and move assignment are marked noexcept. Therefore, it is important to have these implemented for heavy objects when using algorithms. If they are not available and exception free, the elements will be copied instead.

To break my question into pieces:

1. Are there code paths in the standard library similar to the `std::vector::push_back`, that run faster when fed with `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` types?
2. Am I correct to conclude that the cited paragraph from the book is not correct?
3. Is there an obvious example for when the compiler will reliably generate more runtime-efficient code when a type adheres to the `noexcept` guideline?

I know the third one might be a bit blurry. But if someone could come up with a simple example, this would be great.

Comment: If your move constructor may throw, you should be able to justify that with strong arguments. Not the other way around.

Comment: Well I absolutely agree with the guideline. But it seems that the semantics aspect is far more important than the performance one.

Comment: I've found a couple inaccuracies in that book myself, so it's not a very reliable resource. I agree that the semantics aspect is the important part. Functions that take by value and move  are usually marked `noexcept` and a throwing move constructor would break that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Background: I refer to `std::vector`'s use of noexcept as "the `vector` pessimization." I claim that the `vector` pessimization is the only reason anyone ever cared about putting a `noexcept` keyword into the language. Furthermore, the `vector` pessimization applies *only* to the element type's move constructor. I claim that marking your move-assignment or swap operations as `noexcept` has no "in-game effect"; leaving aside whether it might be philosophically satisfying or stylistically correct, you shouldn't expect it to have any effect on your code's performance.

Let's check a real library implementation and see how close I am to wrong. ;)

- Vector reallocation. libc++'s headers use `move_if_noexcept` *only* inside `__construct_{forward,backward}_with_exception_guarantees`, which is used *only* inside vector reallocation.
- Assignment operator for `variant`. Inside `__assign_alt`, the code tag-dispatches on `is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Tp, _Arg> || !is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<_Tp>`. When you do `myvariant = arg;`, the default "safe" approach is to construct a temporary `_Tp` from the given `arg`, and then destroy the currently emplaced alternative, and then move-construct that temporary `_Tp` into the new alternative (which hopefully won't throw). However, if we know that the `_Tp` is nothrow-constructible directly from `arg`, we'll just do that; or, if `_Tp`'s move-constructor is throwing, such that the "safe" approach isn't actually safe, then it's not buying us anything and we'll just do the fast direct-construction approach anyway.

Btw, the assignment operator for `optional` does *not* do any of this logic.

Notice that for `variant` assignment, having a noexcept move constructor actually *hurts* (unoptimized) performance, unless you have also marked the selected converting constructor as `noexcept`! [Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/vPjasq)

(This experiment also turned up an apparent bug in libstdc++: [#99417](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99417).)

- `string` appending/inserting/assigning. This is a surprising one. `string::append` makes a call to `__append_forward_unsafe` under a SFINAE check for `__libcpp_string_gets_noexcept_iterator`. When you do `s1.append(first, last)`, we'd like to do `s1.resize(s1.size() + std::distance(first, last))` and then copy into those new bytes. However, this doesn't work in three situations: (1) If `first, last` point into `s1` itself. (2) If `first, last` are exactly `input_iterator`s (e.g. reading from an `istream_iterator`), such that it's known impossible to iterate the range twice. (3) If it's possible that iterating the range once could put it into a bad state where iterating the second time would *throw*. That is, if any of the operations in the second loop (`++`, `==`, `*`) are non-noexcept. So in any of those three situations, we take the "safe" approach of constructing a temporary `string s2(first, last)` and then `s1.append(s2)`. [Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/Wxj97d)

I would bet money that the logic controlling this `string::append` optimization is incorrect. ([EDIT: yes, it is.](https://godbolt.org/z/zsj98s)) See ["Attribute `noexcept_verify`"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/12/attribute-noexcept-verify/#the-upside) (2018-06-12). Also [observe in that godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Wxj97d) that the operation whose noexceptness matters to libc++ is `rv == rv`, but the one it actually *calls* inside `std::distance` is `lv != lv`.

The same logic applies even harder in `string::assign` and `string::insert`. We need to iterate the range while modifying the string. So we need *either* a guarantee that the iterator operations are noexcept, *or* a way to "back out" our changes when an exception is thrown. And of course for `assign` in particular, there's not going to be any way to "back out" our changes. The only solution in that case is to copy the input range into a temporary `string` and then assign from that `string` (because we know `string::iterator`'s operations are noexcept, so they can use the optimized path).

libc++'s `string::replace` does *not* do this optimization; it always copies the input range into a temporary `string` first.

- `function` SBO. libc++'s `function` uses its small buffer only when the stored callable object `is_nothrow_copy_constructible` (and of course is small enough to fit). In that case, the callable is treated as a sort of "copy-only type": even when you move-construct or move-assign the `function`, the stored callable will be copy-constructed, not move-constructed. `function` doesn't even require that the stored callable be move-constructible at all!
- `any` SBO. libc++'s `any` uses its small buffer only when the stored callable object `is_nothrow_move_constructible` (and of course is small enough to fit). Unlike `function`, `any` treats "move" and "copy" as distinct type-erased operations.

Btw, libc++'s `packaged_task` SBO doesn't care about throwing move-constructors. Its noexcept move-constructor will happily call the move-constructor of a user-defined callable: [Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/1YeeG6) This results in a call to `std::terminate` if the callable's move-constructor ever actually does throw. (Confusingly, the error message printed to the screen makes it look as if an exception is escaping out the top of `main`; but that's not actually what's happening internally. It's just escaping out the top of `packaged_task(packaged_task&&) noexcept` and being halted there by the `noexcept`.)

---

Some conclusions:

- To avoid the `vector` pessimization, you must declare your move-constructor noexcept. I still think this is a good idea.
- If you declare your move-constructor noexcept, then to avoid the "`variant` pessimization," you must *also* declare all your single-argument converting constructors noexcept. However, the "`variant` pessimization" merely costs a single move-construct; it does *not* degrade all the way into a copy-construct. So you can probably eat this cost safely.
- Declaring your copy constructor `noexcept` can enable small-buffer optimization in libc++'s `function`. However, this matters only for things that are (A) callable and (B) very small and (C) *not* in possession of a defaulted copy constructor. I think this describes the empty set. Don't worry about it.
- Declaring your iterator's operations `noexcept` can enable a (dubious) optimization in libc++'s `string::append`. But literally *nobody* cares about this; and besides, the optimization's logic is buggy anyway. I'm very much considering submitting a patch to rip out that logic, which will make this bullet point obsolete. (EDIT: Patch [submitted](https://reviews.llvm.org/D98573), and also [blogged](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/04/17/pathological-string-appends/).)

I'm not aware of anywhere else in libc++ that cares about noexceptness. If I missed something, please tell me! I'd also be very interested to see similar rundowns for libstdc++ and Microsoft.

Comment: That's a very detailed analysis, unfortunately a bit depressing :) Thanks!

Comment: This answer seems to focus on benefits of `noexcept` from the point of view of the library explicitly checking for it to allow for optimizations.  But what about the generated code from the compiler generally?  Will the presence of `noexcept` allow the compiler to generate more compact code, e.g. omitting boilerplate for exception propagation?

Comment: @dpacbach: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2022/07/30/type-erased-inplace-printable/#benefits-from-noexcept is relevant to your interests. Basically, `noexcept` can indeed be useful for optimizations if it is placed at an ABI boundary — a function pointer, virtual function, or function whose body isn't visible to the caller — and then the function is tail-called from a noexcept context (such as a destructor). In practice I don't think ordinary programmers need to be concerned with that, though; when `noexcept` matters, it is newsworthy because it is _surprising_.

Answer (score 4):

vector push_back, resize, reserve, etc is very important  case, as it is expected to be the most used container.

Anyway, take look at `std::fuction` as well, I'd expect it to take advantage of noexcept move for small object optimization version.

That is, when functor object is small, and it has `noexcept` move constructor, it can be stored in a small buffer in `std::function` itself, not on heap. But if the functor doesn't have `noexcept` move constructor, it has to be on heap (and don't move when `std::function` is moved)

Overall, there ain't too many cases indeed.

Comment: Now, that's a good example I didn't know about.